# What is the difference between request->merge() and request->add() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is the difference between request->merge() and request->add() in Laravel

I know both of them  they add new key-value to input request but whats difference ?

Comment: Why not inspect the code for differences?

Answer (score 3):

The method `add()` is not defined on the [class Request](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) of Illuminate\Http, it is defined on the [class `ParameterBag`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php) of Symfony\HttpFoundation which is the result of calling the protected method `getInputSource()`.

The method `merge()` does that for you

```
public function merge(array $input)
{
    $this->getInputSource()->add($input);

    return $this;
}
```

Nothing that you can't discover with test and source code reading